# Экранировать символ в регулярке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.

Есть регулярное выражение `^.*[^a-zA-Z]{2,}.*$`
В Chrome, когда ставлю символ `[` падает ошибка. Нужно как-то его экранировать. В нете нашёл вот такое выражение `\[`. Но оно не работает или может я не в том месте вставлял.

Делаю вот так для input `minlength="10" pattern="^.*[^a-zA-Z]{2,}.*$"`

Подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Приложите js код. Вставлять в chrome - дело такое, много куда там можно вставить)

Comment: Добавьте скрин развернутой ошибки

Comment: Какие строки нужно найти, а какие нет? Зачем вам вообще тут такое странное регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 0):

Тестил в: ff, safari, chrome, edge - работает везде

```js
$('input').change(function(e){
    let regExp = e.target.attributes.pattern.value,
   v = e.target.value.match(regExp);
    v ? alert('regExp PASSED') : alert('regExp FAILED');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" minlength="10" pattern="^.*[[][[^a-zA-Z]{2,}.*$">
```

[regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/H24gqi/2)

Comment: Это баг какой-то в ангуляре

Comment: Так добавьте ошибку, если ещё нужна помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте поставить двойной слэш. \ 
А вообще конечно все у вас должно работать - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Проверти вообще правильность регулярного выражение в каком нибудь online ресурсе.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду вот так?

`^.*\\[[^a-zA-Z]{2,}.*$`